# What are the advantages to Perforce?

Tags: svn, version-control, perforce

What are the benefits of Perforce?

I'd love to have some insight as to how Perforce can work better in a given situation than, say, Subversion.

If you have experience with both Perforce and Subversion and you don't believe that there are any advantages, or believe that svn has advantages over Perforce, I'd like to know why, as well.

Comment: Perforce rocks. I have used SVN, visual source safe, and other systems. I have also used perforce for several years. I wouldn't run a commercial project on anything else.

Answer (score 22):

I've worked with Perforce for years, as well as Clearcase, Sourcesafe, RCS, PVCS, CVS and Subversion. More recently I've started using GIT too.

From this experience my opinion is that, for most purposes, Perforce is the best version control system for commercial environments. While not as simple, initially, as Subversion, it has a number of more powerful features, especially around branching and merging. The "lock by default" approach is generally more suited to this environment.

For personal stuff, small collaborative projects, small start-ups, or open source projects I find Subversion is better suited in many cases. They have different approaches, different ways of working. You can't just line them up on a scale and say which is best.

That said I hate ClearCase. ClearCase is usually forced down from above (ie a management decision).

For many of the cases where Subversion trumps Perforce many people seem to prefer the distributed systems like GIT, Bazaar, Mercurial, these days. From what I have seen of GIT they may well be right and I'm sure other posters will bear that out.

Comment: Phil - you are entirely allowed your own opinion of Clearcase, but I'd be interested as to why you 'hate' it? What was it that drove you to such anger? :)

Comment: It's an opinion shared by most of my co-workers :-)
ClearCase is heavy, slow, and complex. It is particularly bad at bulk check-ins, and doesn't have a concept of associating files together that are checked in at the same time (like Perforce's changelists). I'd say more but I'm out of characters!

Comment: Clearcase is enterprisey, unintuitive, and doesn't have atomic checkins. I'm obliged to use it occasionally, and not once have I got by without tripping over something stupid.

Comment: ClearCase does allow atomic checkins with UCM.

Answer (score 16):

One of Perforce's big selling points is speed. The server keeps track of the state of the files on the client; therefore, operations like "get me the latest state of the depot" are trivial -- the server already knows what files you have, and it can send the minimal amount of information back to you.

This advantage also introduces a disadvantage, in that the server and client can get out of sync if you edit files locally without checking them out first, move files locally without carrying out an integration, or delete files locally.

Because the Perforce server only sends the bare minimum of data to the client, Perforce performs well over slow links, such as a situation where a client in the US accesses a depot in London. Having said that, the Perforce protocol is relatively 'chatty', so it is susceptible to slowdown over congested links.

Comment: I agree with your commented disadvantage, especially if you can't connect to the server for some reason.

It's easy to get Perforce to resolve the issue though:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/266771/detecting-perforce-unopened-modified-files

Comment: Yep, it's called 'Force Resync'.

Comment: This idea of disadvantage is from folks who aren't VCS aware. The local files are RO until you check them out. It takes real effort to do the wrong thing. And, even if the wrong thing should happen, it won't happen twice...

Comment: "One of Perforce's big selling points is speed"...

Well... Currently I'm in a big integration, and it has been merging something for 5 hours...

Comment: @Calmarius Upgrade the disks on the server. Perforce network traffic is designed to be fast, but it will eat all of the server resources it can get. In particular, integrations benefit from fast I/O.

Comment: @TimRobinson Well if your integration changelist contains gigabytes (because some loser in our company decided to store binaries in p4). It will download all files that's needs integration, and it seems there is no option tell perforce not to do so... (at least in this ancient 2009.2 server).

Comment: @Calmarius Sorry to hear that - I'd say you're stuck. Hope whoever checked in the binaries buys you a coffee while you wait...

Answer (score 11):

I use perforce at work daily and I would not recommend it to anyone. I'm sure it *was* maybe the best SCM for years but it's core model is outdated.

Perforce is maybe the *most* centralized SCM system I ever used. Imagine that they are proud of not caching anything on your disk. Doing a sync is annoying because in a huge number of cases it will do nothing unless you do not do a forced sync - and a forced sync does copy everything from the server back to you - if your project is 10GB it will copy all of them.

I have previous experience using SourceSafe, CVS, SVN, Mercurial and git (less of the last two).

I think that most open-source SCMs are mature and you can choose one of the. If you want something centralized go for SVN and if you want something decentralized use Mercurial (I had bad experiences with git on Windows).

Some other issues I had with perforce:

- what you commit is not what you get back: for example if you commit an UTF16 file on an Intel Mac and sync it from another PPC Mac you'll get another UTF16 file because perforce is smart and does covert you the file to the client byte-ordering. UTF16-BE - UTF16-LE ?!
- scripting perforce is 10x times harder than other tools.
- if you start using it and tie it to your processes by scripting probably you'll die with it because everything is done in perforce way and perforce way :(
- image that it's very easy to get down a p4 server: just do sync on the root of the project. Where I work this is not allowed because it can take the serve down! There is a watching script that is monitoring the perforce server processes and if one of them is taking over x GB of RAM it does kill it and send you a notification. Yes, doing one simple command on the client can create a 3GB process on the server in 5-10 seconds.

Comment: I disagree with almost every statement you've made here. File encoding is configurable, if you set up Perforce incorrectly, that's not their fault. Scripting is awesome, and with so many languages supported (Java/Python/Ruby/.NET etc) the barrier to entry is pretty low. The scripting of an SCM is almost always bespoke to chosen software, I can't think of a single case where this is not the case. I can't really comment on taking a server down as I've never seen it happen, even syncing the entire depot between the UK and Australia.

Comment: I respect you opinion, but do not forget that "entire depot" can be something very different from one company to another. I have lots of files (6 digits!) and over 30GB of data on a single depot.

Comment: @sorin Not sure how Perforce is setup at your company but we host over 7 digits worth of files on our depot and what you say never happens. Something tells me that something is messed up with your configuring.

Answer (score 8):

Perforce has the a bit different model than, say, svn. Every file is always locked in your working copy, and you have to declare to perforce you'll start editing it.
This has e.g. the advantage that you can always immediatly see who else is working on a file.

All in all differences with other SCM's aren't very huge. You encounter Perforce in many places because at a time it was one of the few (if not the only) partially decent SCM that worked on Windows and Mac.

If I'm not mistaken you can use it for free with a limited number of clients, so you can try it out without much pain...

Comment: Locking is not enforced, only on binary files (Which can't be merged). Several people can work on the same ASCII (eg Source code) file together though, and later merge them.

Comment: There is a free 2-developers-only license for Perforce.

Comment: It's also very easy to get temporary from Perforce to test it out for your team.  Just call and ask and you can get about as many licenses as you need, for free, for 30 or 60 days.

Comment: You can configure Perforce workspaces to not require checkout before editing. It's part of the workspace specification.

Answer (score 6):

Personally, I despise perforce. It's user interface is horrible, complicated, and simply non intuitive. It is buggy and crashes often.

I have worked with SVN before (via Tortoise SVN) and have found it much more simple and friendly.

Of course all of this is from a users point of view, probably SCMs have a different perspective

Comment: I totally disagree. I have been working with Perforce for the last 6 years. Crashes are seldom, maybe 5 years ago but today's Perforce is rock solid. The UI you have to learn, or you just use the newer P4V instead, which has a more "windows" conformist UI.

Comment: I would point you to P4WSAD (perforce-eclipse integration) which is buggy to death. In any case, UX is totally objective , hence the "personally" in the beginning of my answer.

Comment: I don't think it's fair to judge the whole SCM on the merit (or lack thereof) of an optional plugin. I use Perforce daily, with Java but without the plugin. I just handle the source control outside of Eclipse. Easy as.

Comment: The perforce clients (windows) have never ever crashed on me.

Comment: Yes, Eclipse integration with many things is buggy to death. Kind of unfair to judge a tool based on this one specific use case.

Comment: @CJohnson It does not crash, but it experiences problems often where it stops responding (continuously waiting for the server, even though the server is up). And "Cancel" button does not work in that instance so you have to restart (and usually force kill the application to do so). The other thing that often happens after running it for a while is that it gets stuck and starts eating 100% of a core's CPU and you have to kill it. Maybe not crashing per se, but definitely not a stable application that you can just leave running all the time.

Answer (score 5):

You might find hints in [What are the benefits of using Perforce instead of Subversion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157429/what-are-the-benefits-of-using-perforce-instead-of-subversion) (just following your Perforce tag...).

We use Perforce at work and while I have little experience with various SCM software, I find this one quite well done, with a good GUI (on Windows), good command line support, lot of nice features... Might take a while to get used to its logic, but it is probably true for most SCM, I think.

Answer (score 4):

Perforce supports locking, and seems to require it for some file types that cannot be merged (binary resources, think images etc). It does *not*, however, require locking for ordinary source files, those can be opened for editing by multiple users at the same time, and then merged back into the depot.

I find Perforce's system with "changelists", that group changes to multiple files and treat them as a unit, nice. I'm sure you can do something similiar with SVN, but it's not as easy out of the box.

Comment: Actually SVN does work much the same way as changelists. Every version number is repository wide, so if you roll back to a version you roll back the entire repository.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the previous Yuval - having worked with Perforce and svn, both in GUI and command-line mode, I prefer svn. However, the company I worked for at the time switched from the free cvs it was using to Perforce. Its GUI is flashier. I think its commit model is different - it uses locking, which may be preferable to some developers/managers. In a commercial setting, having support people for your version control tool may help too. 
I have heard that in some large companies using open-source code in production environments is forbidden, because they want to be able to get support for every line of code.

Answer (score -1):

A Perforce server can **read and write arbitrary files on the client, and thus execute arbitrary code.** The Perforce configuration is all server-side, so the server could simply treat the entire hard disc of the clients' computer as a repository, and do **whatever it wanted to it.**

Never run Perforce except in an SELinux sandbox.

**Remember: The Perforce client is the server's puppet.** You must use the operating system's security features to prevent it from doing something you don't want it to do. **ALWAYS treat the Perforce client as hostile.**

Comment: There is no server-side control of code execution on the client. Do you have proof of this claim?

Comment: Yes.  The server controls where the repository ends, so it can tell the client to overwrite any file.

Comment: That action is controlled by the client. And you have 100% control over when it happens. If you don't want it to happen, you can just not synchronize the client.