# Detecting Perforce unopened modified files

Tags: perforce

I'm trying to figure out a way to detect files that are not opened for editing but have nevertheless been modified locally. `p4 fstat` returns a value `headModTime` for any given file, but this is the change time in the depot, which should not be equal to the filesystem's `stat` last modified time.

I'm hoping that there exists a more lightweight operation than backing up the original file, forcing a sync of the file, and then running a diff. Ideas?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

From: http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB/3481/?q=disconnected&l=en_US&fs=Search&pn=1

See step 2 specifically:

---

2 . Next, open for "edit" any files that have changed:

```
p4 diff -se //myclient/... | p4 -x - edit
```

p4 diff -se returns the names of depot files whose corresponding client file differs in any way from the clients #have revision.

Comment: For those who, like me, spend little time in the command line, here's quick and dirty way to do the diff without having to permanently set up your p4 environment. Use your own values for stuff in brackets:  p4 -c <workspace> -p <server>:<port> -P <pass> diff -se

Comment: `p4 -x -`  is "read argument from file, if - then use stdin".

Answer (score 23):

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9272/finding-untracked-files-in-a-perforce-tree) gives a way to do this in the P4V GUI:

> In the Jan 2009 version of P4V, you can right-click on any folder in your workspace tree and click "reconcile offline work..."
>
> This will do a little processing then bring up a split-tree view of files that are not checked out but have differences from the depot version, or not checked in at all. There may even be a few other categories it brings up.
>
> You can right-click on files in this view and check them out, add them, or even revert them.

Later EDIT:

In the "Reconcile..." window, you can click 'Advanced Reconcile' and be presented with a two-pane, folder hierarchy diff window which is especially useful for finding files you need to add.

PROS: This whole P4V feature is more user-friendly than the command-line version (because it allows utmost granularity in selecting what to reconcile)

CONS: It is in dire need of a subversion/git/hg `.ignore`-like list, to spare you the pain of manually skipping all the dll's and other cruft in your projects.

Comment: having used p4v now for a year, I like this answer a lot. benefit is that this method also finds files for add (files not under source control in your workspace). if you have lots of garbage intermediate object clutter in your workspace, it can be a bit of a pain though.

Comment: The command line in 2012.2 is really easy now. 'p4 reconcile <path>'.

Comment: @Epu you should add (move?) that comment to the accepted answer, it will be easier to spot for people looking for the command-line way of doing this.

Comment: Yes, it's useless without being able to exclude crud (a la .gitignore) . See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55449/can-you-ignore-a-file-in-perforce/13126496#13126496

Comment: We've discovered an interesting issue at work on Windows with UAC enabled, where files of type symlink transform into textfiles (default behavior when UAC is on). Reconcile always picks up the transformed files. So, yeah, it's not without errors.

Comment: this still works in the Perforce Visual Client 2013 edition =)

Answer (score 4):

As of Perforce version 2012.1, use the command line commands `p4 status` and `p4 reconcile`

http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r12.2/manuals/cmdref/status.html

> The `p4 status` command finds unopened files in a client's workspace and  detects the following three types of inconsistencies between your workspace and the depot:
>
> 1. Files present in the depot, present in your have list, but missing from your workspace. By default, these files are then opened for
>    delete.
> 2. Files present in your workspace, but missing on the depot. By default, these files are opened for add.
> 3. Files modified in your workspace that are not open for edit. By default, these files are opened for edit.

http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r12.1/manuals/cmdref/reconcile.html

Answer (score 2):

From the working disconnected article, using p4win you can also select the folder/files in question and select 'file menu->more->check consistency' which basically does the 'p4 diff -se' and 'p4 diff -sd', and prompts the user to resolve the inconsistencies.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a unix solution that has worked very well for me.

[How to find untracked files in a Perforce tree? (analogue of svn status)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9272/finding-untracked-files-in-a-perforce-tree/100126#100126)